# Lambda-функция в генераторе/цикле: неверный подсчет значения?

Tags: python, функции, lambda

Почему получается 125?

```
funcs = [lambda x: x**i for i in range(2, 4)]
print(funcs[0](5))
```

> 125

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268482/7485582

Answer (score 5):

Потому, что для анонимных функций, создаваемых на каждом шаге, `i` - внешняя изменяемая переменная, и обращение к ней идет не по ссылке, а по имени, а значит берется не то значение `i`, что было на момент создания функции, а то, что было на момент ее вызова. Вот другой пример

```py
i = 0

def f():
    return i

print(f()) # 0
i = 10
print(f()) # 10
```

Или даже так

```py
def f():
    return i

# print(f()) # если раскомментировать, примедет к ошибке, значение i еще не задано
i = 10
print(f()) # 10
```

Чтобы избежать этого, можно передать `i` неявным параметром, тогда обращение к `i` по имени будет происходить только в момент создания функции.

```py
funcs = [lambda x, current_i=i: x**current_i for i in range(2, 4)]
```

или другим способом зафиксировать значение `i` на момент создания функции, передав его в неизменяемый параметр внешней функции

```py
funcs = [(lambda current_i: lambda x: x**current_i)(i) for i in range(2, 4)]
```

но тогда проще будет использовать `map`, который сделает это за вас.

```py
funcs = list(map(lambda i: lambda x: x**i, range(2, 4)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Кстати, легко ведь проверить, что именно происходит, если добавить в вывод все параметры:

```
funcs = [lambda x: (x,i,x**i) for i in range(2, 4)]
print(funcs[0](5))
# (5, 3, 125)
```

Т.е. `5**3 = 125`, `i == 3`.

Ну а почему так и как починить, уже написали в других ответах.

```
funcs = [lambda x, i=i: (x,i,x**i) for i in range(2, 4)]
print(funcs[0](5))
# (5, 2, 25)
```

Answer (score 2):

`range(2, 4)` - создаёт список из двух элементов `[2, 3]`, и ваш for проходится по нему 1 раз.

```
funcs = [lambda x: x**i for i in range(2, 4)]
print(funcs[0](5)]
>>> 125

# вот что происходит
# 5**2 = 25
# 5**3 = 125
```

вот синтаксис, ссылка на документацию по `range`: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Comment: `25**2 = 125 `?

Comment: 1. `range` не создает список. 2. Как это объясняет, что результаты вызовов двух функций идентичны? 3. w3school - это не официальная документация.

Comment: @user207200 а что он делает?

Comment: Возвращает объект класса последовательности.

Comment: @user207200 это разве не список?

Comment: Нет, но они происходят от одного родителя `collections.abc.Sequence`.

Comment: А можно ссылку, на документ, где можно прочитать про то, что range возвращает не список?

Comment: Опечатался, дайте документацию, что range не возвращает список.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Comment: соглашусь, спасибо

Comment: @strawdog исправил, спасибо, не прав был

Comment: @S.Nick  исправил, спасибо, не прав был